# How is this circle inversion formula calculated?

Tags: geometry, circles, inversive-geometry

I know about the inversion of a point inside a circle. But I was reading Peter Sarnak's paper on the Apollonian gasket, and got to the part where he was trying to prove descartes circle theorem. He described this circle inversion. Could someone please derive it?
[image: inversion of a circle]

Comment: Do you know the image of a circle under inversion is itself a circle? If so, that simplifies the proof.... :)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I do. But I'd like to learn more about the geometry of the expression in the image (basically how it was derived). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sketch**: Without loss of generality, assume the circle $E$ is centered at the origin. Inversion in $E$ is given in Cartesian coordinates by
$$
(x, y) \mapsto (u, v) := \frac{k^{2}}{x^{2} + y^{2}}(x, y).
\tag{1}
$$
Particularly,
$$
x^{2} + y^{2} = \frac{k^{4}}{u^{2} + v^{2}}.
\tag{2}
$$
The circle $C$ has equation
$$
(x - d)^{2} + y^{2} = r^{2}.
\tag{3}
$$
Expand (3), substitute (2), and rearrange in the obvious way to get the equation of a circle. (Since you're reading Sarnak, this should be routine.)

If you're primarily interested in calculating the radius, put the center of $E$ at the origin and the center of $C$ at $(d, 0)$, so $C$ cuts the horizontal axis at $x_{1} = d + r$ and $x_{2} = d - r$. The image of $C$ under inversion crosses the horizontal axis at
$$
x_{1}' = \frac{k}{x_{1}},\qquad
x_{2}' = \frac{k}{x_{2}};
$$
the radius of the image is therefore $\frac{1}{2}|x_{2}' - x_{1}'|$, which is easily checked to be
$$
\frac{k^{2}r}{d^{2} - r^{2}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks so much Mr. Hwang :)

Comment: Hi Andrew, could you please expand on how you got (2)?

Comment: aaaaaah nevermind, i've figured it out!

Comment: You're very welcome. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I have ran across the exact same problem but in inversion under a sphere, instead of a circle. I've applied this formula for the radius to my program, in my case for the reflected sphere, but unfortunately it seems to be slightly off. Would you happen to know why this can't be applied to the sphere by simply adding another coordinate? Or is it supposed to work and there's something wrong with my program?